# Variable name with another variable value on it to achieve less repetitions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, refactoring, capybara-webkit

I'm working on the refactor of my `RSpec`+ `capybara-webkit` tests, and I
I'm trying to not have lot of repetitions.
So I created this method that I will call various times during the tests:

```
def fill(field1, value1, field2, value2, field3, value3, button)
 fill_in field1, :with => value1
 fill_in field2, :with => value2
 fill_in field3, :with => value3
 find(button).click
end
```

And this is my test:

```
describe "Test", :js => true do
 it "fill fields" do
  fill('first_field', 'first_value', 'second_field', 'second_value, 'third_field', 'third_value', 'input.button')
 end
end
```

I'd like to have something  very simple like

```
def fill(field1, value1, field2, value2, field3, value3, button)
 for i in 1..3 do
  fill_in field+"#{i}", :with => value+"#{i}"
 end
 find(button).click
end
```

but I cannot achieve it so easily.

I tried also with

```
def fill(field1, value1, field2, value2, field3, value3, button)
 for i in 1..3 do
  fill_in "field#{i}", :with => "value#{i}"
 end
 find(button).click
end
```

but `RSpec` will search for a field called "field1" and not for "first_field" (that I'm passing to the method).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should pass a hash of fields and values:

```
def fill(button, h)
  h.each{|field, value| fill_in field, with: value}
  find(button).click
end

describe "Test", js: true do
  it "fill fields" do
    fill('input.button', 'first_field' => 'first_value', 'second_field' => 'second_value', 'third_field' => 'third_value')
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution that will work for any *n* pairs of fields and values:

```
def fill(fields, values, button)
    (fields.zip values).each { |field, value| fill_in field, :with => value }
    find(button).click
end
```

The call is a little different:

```
fill(['first_field', 'second_field', 'thrid_field'], ['first_value', 'second_value', 'third_value'], 'input.button')
```

Comment: I see not reason for using `Hash[]` and `each`. You can directly pass the block to `zip`.

Comment: Thanks @sawa, I updated the answer as to not use Hash. I don't understand what you mean by "there is no reason to use `each`", could you detail a little more on what you're thinking?

Answer (score -1):

```
(1..3).each do |i|
  fill_in eval("field#{i}"), with: eval("value#{1}")
end
```

Comment: As i said in the question, i tried something like this but it will look for a filed called "field1" that it's not what i'm looking for

Comment: @fabersky This answer is different from what you tried. The evaluated value of `eval("field#{i}")` is `"first_field"` and so on.

Comment: @sawa I do not care about downvotes; appreciate the upvote though. Being afraid of `eval` in tests is just insane.

Comment: Needlessly using `eval` to solve this problem is equally insane.

Comment: @meagar Assuming you are the moderator, you probably able to read the question title, which apparently is “Variable name with another variable value on it to achieve less repetitions.” The upvoted and selected answers both suggest the different approach, mine resolves the problem that was stated in the title. Whether you might think that answering questions as they stated is “needless insanity,” I keep my own opinion on the topic.